# How can I set the default target es version for the typescript compiler (tsc)?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, terminal, tsc

I've spent a lot of the last 24hrs learning:

- how Visual Studio Code works
- how TypeScript works
- how the TypeScript Compiler (`tsc`) works
- how these three pieces of software all fit together

In less than a day (!) I finally succeeded in writing some basic TypeScript and compiling it to Javascript.

My ecstasy was a little muted when I discovered that the TypeScript Compiler (`tsc`) had not only compiled the static type labels, but had also *transpiled*:

- `const`

into:

- `var`

I say *muted*, but actually I was *mildly horrified*.

Then I discovered that the default transpilation target for `tsc` is **ECMAScript 3**.

It turns out, I can keep my `const` declarations constant, by invoking `tsc` with a `--target` flag:

```
tsc my-first-typescript.ts --target es6
```

However. I really don't want to keep writing `--target es6` (or `--target es11`) every time I invoke `tsc`.

Is there any way I can set the default transpilation target version for `tsc` so that it doesn't automatically assume I want javascript like it's 1999?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can globally change the *default* (well, you could modify the `tsc` file, but...), but you can set the options (including target) for any given project using a `tsconfig.json` file in the project root; details in the **Project Configuration** section of the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html). E.g.:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2015"
    }
}
```

You don't necessarily have to roll your own, either, the [`tsconfig/bases` project](https://github.com/tsconfig/bases#centralized-recommendations-for-tsconfig-bases) on GitHub is designed to make it easy to get up and running with configs for various project types.

Comment: Thank you, @T.J.Crowder - a little more experimenting and I finally got it to work. The issue is outlined here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6591 Basically it's this: a workspace may be created and a `tsconfig.json` added to it. **But** any command in the terminal which references a filename like: `tsc my-first-typescript.ts` means that the `tsconfig.json` is ignored. Instead, the command _needs to be_ `tsc` (ie. without any filenames) and then the `tsconfig.json` will be consulted.

Comment: To be fair, on the relevant page of the **TypeScript Handbook** (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html), it does also state unambigously that: _"When input files are specified on the command line, `tsconfig.json` files are ignored."_

Answer (score 2):

Haven't found a way to configure *tsc* itself; but declaring a global `tscFlags` variable works just fine.

This is in Powershell, but am sure there is an equivalent way in bash/unix.

**Declare [global] array in profile/imported module**:

```
$tscFlags = @(
    # Flags
    '--noEmitOnError'
    '--strict'
    '--alwaysStrict'
    '--noFallthroughCasesInSwitch'
    '--noImplicitAny'
    '--noImplicitReturns'
    '--noImplicitThis'
    '--noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature'
    '--noUncheckedIndexedAccess'
    '--noUnusedLocals'
    '--noUnusedParameters'
    '--strictBindCallApply'
    '--strictFunctionTypes'
    '--strictNullChecks'
    '--strictPropertyInitialization'
    # Options
    '-t'
    'ES2020'
)
```

`PS C:\> tsc <file.ts> @tscFlags`

You can add more flags manually after/before the ['splatted'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7.2) `@tscFlags` call.